# js is merged automatically in magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

When I disable js merge it is **merged again automatically.** I don't know how. I there any way to check why or how it is happening?

If js is merged Admin menu and submit button is not working. I tried to change the sequence of js files in main.xml as mentioned below, it didn't work.

1. Always include jQuery before any other script on your page, before Prototype is a must.
2. Add jQuery.noConflict(); call directly to the end of your jQuery library file.

**My main concern is, js should not merge automatically.**

**my main.xml file**

```
<action method="setTitle" translate="title"><title>Magento Admin</title></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>extjs/fix-defer-before.js</name><params/><if/><condition>can_load_ext_js</condition></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/window.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js?version=2.5</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>

                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/hash.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/events.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/loader.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/grid.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/tabs.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/form.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/accordion.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/tools.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/uploader.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/product.js</script></action>
```

website purchaseglory.com

Comment: System -> Cache Management -> Select * and Submit to refresh cache..

Comment: when I open your site, it get no merged js? did you solved it?

Comment: I have kept it disable. As it is messing up all the drop downs and submit buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if clearing the cache is not working then head to admin and:

System -> Configuration -> Advanced (Developer) and put settings to `no` for merging of js files

[image]

Comment: This is how I disable it every time. But it is automatically changed. I want to figure out why it is changed to Yes again and again?

Comment: do you have any module installed that changes admin settings automatically? What scope are you trying to change that setting under: default config, main website or store view?

Comment: Settings are done under Default config scope. I have multiple modules installed. But I don't think it is because of any module. Since I have added this question, the problem never occurred again. So I couldn't verify any of the things you told. I will comment if anything comes up. Thank you!